# Segmentation fault while checking size of bitset

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, bitset

I get a segmentation fault when I try to run the code below. I've tried commenting out bits of the code, and found that the while loop with the condition `j < is_prime.size()` is the culprit. This is puzzling to me because I perform the same check between the same values in the for loop above it, but do not get a segmentation fault.

Could someone explain to me what's the issue here?

I'm using GCC 4.8.2 on Linux 64.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const size_t max_pandigital = 987654321;

int main()
{
    bitset<max_pandigital/3> is_prime;
    is_prime.set();                  // assume all numbers are prime
    is_prime[0] = false;             // 1 is not prime
    for(size_t i = 1; i < is_prime.size(); i++) {
        if(is_prime[i]) {
            int n;
            if(i%2 == 0) n = 3*i+1;
            else n = 3*i+2;
            size_t j = i;
            if(j%2 == 0) j += n-2;
            else j += n+2;
            while(j < is_prime.size()) {
                is_prime[j] = false;
                if(j%2 == 0) j += n-2;
                else j += n+2;
            }
        }
    }
    //cout << is_prime[899809363/3] << endl;
}
```

Edit: I implemented some of the changes suggested. Here's a working version - runs in ~13s. I think the biggest bottleneck is allocating the 42MB for the bool vector. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const size_t max_pandigital = 987654321;

int main()
{
    vector<bool> not_prime(max_pandigital/3);
    not_prime[0] = true;             // 1 is not prime
    for(size_t i = 1; i < not_prime.size(); i++) {
        if(~not_prime[i]) {
            int n;
            if(i%2 == 0) n = 3*i+1;
            else n = 3*i+2;
            size_t j = i;
            if(j%2 == 0) j += n-2;
            else j += n+2;
            while(j < not_prime.size()) {
                not_prime[j] = true;
                if(j%2 == 0) j += n-2;
                else j += n+2;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << not_prime[899809363/3] << endl; // prime
    cout << not_prime[100017223/3] << endl; // pseudoprime
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that it segfaults when you comment in the commented-out code? If so then edit your post to not comment that stuff out.   As it stands you just have an infinite loop with no segfault.

Comment: Right. Segfault either way.

Comment: You can't segfault with the loop empty as it is an infinite loop that does nothing

Comment: I see the infinite loop. If I comment out the while loop and only the while loop, then when I run the program, my terminal does not report a segmentation fault. If I leave it uncommented - even with the guts commented out - I get a segfault. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the commented-out is commented in, and I run your code then I get a segfault due to stack overflow. (Even if the code remains commented out though, the stack still overflowed, which explains what you are seeing).

Typical systems default to a stack size on the order of 1 megabyte; but your bitset requires about 40 megabytes of storage.

To fix this you could either:

- dynamically allocate your bitset
- use a different container such as `vector<bool>`
- tell your environment to use a larger stack size

An example of dynamic allocation might be:

```
unique_ptr< bitset<max_pandigital/3> > ip { new bitset<max_pandigital/3> };
auto &is_prime = *ip;
```

and the rest of the code the same.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as soon as the 5-minute wait period is over.

Could you advise me which is a better solution - increase the stack or use the heap?

Comment: I couldn't say if one was better than the other

Comment: making it store `0` for prime and `1` for not-prime would mean you don't have to do the initial set

Comment: Using the heap would be better than stack since it is non standard how the stack is sized, but if you use the heap it should Just Work and you really don't have to worry about size, unless you're on an embedded system.

Answer (score 1):

You are not guaranteed to segfault when you mess up a reference or fencepost!   The behavior is "undefined", and can be quite troublesome to track down.   Use something like 'valgrind' to find the exact first moment of badness.